Definiiton of 'Annihilator' in the context of dual map
Could you tell me what the definiton of 'annihilator' in this context ?
I know the definition of annihilator for modules over ring, but in the following context, any definition I know means nothing.
Let $A,B$ be an abelian group. $\hat{A}=\text{Hom}(A,\Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z})$,.
Let $f$ be a map $ f : A\to B$, and $\hat{f}:  \hat{B}\to \hat{A}$ be dual of $f$.
Then, in general,$\text{image}(f)$ should be annihilator of
$\text{ker}(\hat{f})$, not equal.

To say that $\mathrm{Im}(f)$ is the annihilator of $\mathrm{Ker}(\hat f)$ means that
$$\mathrm{Im}(f) = \{ b \in B, \forall \lambda \in \mathrm{Ker}(\hat f), \lambda(b) = 0\}.$$

Isn't $b \in \hat{B}$ ?

@Pont No, $\lambda \in \hat B$, so that $\lambda(b)$ makes sense for $b \in B$.
